# Visual Studio changing ownership of edited file

Tags: linux, visual-studio, ubuntu-16.04, samba, ownership

Hi I have Odoo 10 on a Ubuntu Server (16.04) with a Samba share.

Using MS Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.4.0) on my windows desktop....

...when I open a folder - edit a file  - Save - the ownership of that file changes

eg - before edit

```
-rwxrwx---  1 odoo cameron 2 Oct 19 09:05 testfile
```

After VS edit

```
-rwxrwx---+ 1 cameron cameron 2 Oct 19 09:06 testfile
```

Also note the addition of the ACL (access control list) - not that I understand this :(

Leaves me having to edit permissions every edit :(

The samba share is..

```
[odoo]
comment = Odoo
path = /opt
valid user = cameron
guest ok = no
browseable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 2770
directory mask = 2770
```

Any direction greatly appreciated

Cameron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well kind of solved it. I don't understand all of the solution, but hell it works!

As suspected it was Samba config file (smb.conf)

Changed the share to the following settings. (I'm a member of group multzer)

```
[odoo]
comment = Odoo
path = /opt
valid user = @multzer
guest ok = no
browseable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 770
force create mode = 770
security mask = 770
force security mode = 770
directory mask = 2770
force directory mask = 2770
directory security mask = 2770
force directory security mask = 2770
force user = odoo
force group = multzer
```

There seems a lot of FORCING!